# Google Cloud Platform SQL database creation

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, google-cloud-platform

I need to create, among other items, an SQL instance on the google cloud platform. I am required to create the database using Jinja files.

My Yaml file

```
imports:
- path: companyInstance.jinja

resources:

# Creates a database instance
- name: dbinstance11
  type: companyInstance.jinja
```

My companyInstance.jinja

```
resources:
- name: test
  type: sqladmin.v1beta4.instance
  properties:
    zone: europe-west1
    settings:
    - tier: db-custom-4-15360
```

Currently, this should all work as far as I can tell but on a full deployment, I get an error message claiming that `type` is given an `array` type instead of `object`.
The full error is below:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.create) Error in Operation [operation-169876402531-756fgfg342844d-6gd6ebb6-8bb655a]: errors:
- code: CONDITION_NOT_MET
  location: /deployments/dep/resources/test->$.properties
  message: |
    error: instance type (array) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: ["object"])        level: "error"
        schema: {"loadingURI":"#","pointer":"/schemas/Settings"}
        instance: {"pointer":"/settings"}
        domain: "validation"
        keyword: "type"
        found: "array"
        expected: ["object"]
```

Comment: It says the ***settings*** shouldn't be an array. Remove the leading `-` from the last line of the jinja file and try again?

Comment: That is exactly it thankyou so much!